# Query which EditText is selected?

Tags: android, cursor, focus, android-edittext

I have a view with two EditText's and one Button.

When I click the button I want to set the text of the selected EditText.
To set text in a EditText is not my problem.

But how can I query on which of the two EditText is the focus?

Thank you very much for your help!

If you need my specific code, just ask for.

Comment: Please upload that `specific code` of yours for the same in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is method `getCurrentFocus();` in activity, if any of the two edittext is in focus, it will return the editext, else null. The benefit of using this method is, no matter how many edittext you have, it will give you the focus edittext by just a single call.

Comment: Dont you think the focus will be changed as soon as the user clicks on  the Button?

Comment: Anyways it will change the focus. Give it a try

Answer (score 2):

myEditText.hasFocus();
have a condition to check with the above method

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable for the focused EditText:

```
private void focusedEditText = null;
```

Then assign every `EditText` this OnFocusChangeListener:

```
private OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new OnFocusChangeListener(){
      public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
                if(hasFocus){
                  focusedEditText = v;
              } else {
                  focusedEditText = null;
            }
        }
 }
```

You'll then be able to get the focused `EditText` by using `focusedEditText`.